# не могу подключиться по vnc к xrdp

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, xrdp

не могу подключиться по vnc (астра линукс клиент убунту сервер).

по ssh подключаюсь нормально, настроил всё, но почему-то tigervnc хоть и запускается, но при этом соединение не устанавливает (при это и не закрывает).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

судя по тому, что (с большим трудом) получается разобрать на приложенных к вопросу картинках, вы пытаетесь с помощью программы *tigervnc* подключиться к серверу *xrdp*.

---

программа *tigervnc* (как серверная, так и клиентская части) работает по протоколу [rfb (remote framebuffer)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_RFB). (как, собственно, и любой другой [vnc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)-клиент).

а программа *xrdp* (реализация серверной части) работает по протоколу [rdp (remote desktop protocol)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).

*rfb* и *rdp* — это совершенно разные протоколы.

конечно же, существуют [реализации «remote desktop» клиентов и серверов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software), способные работать по обоим протоколам. но программа *tigervnc* работает только по протоколу *rfb*.

---

чтобы подключаться к компьютеру по протоколу *rfb* (используя клиента *tigervnc*), вам надо **на этом компьютере** установить, настроить и запустить *vnc*-сервер. например, тот же самый *tigervnc* (клиентская и серверная части обычно пакуются в разные пакеты).